# Elasticsearch : Sorting an array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch.
The documents I have look something like this :

```
user_name : "test", 
piInfo: {
  profile: {
    word_count: 535,
    word_count_message: "There were 535 words in the input.",
    processed_language: "en",
    personality: [
        {
            name: "Openness",
            category: "personality",
            percentile: 0.0015293409544490655,
            children: []
        },
        {
            name: "Conscientiousness",
            category: "personality",
            percentile: 0.6803430984001135,
            children: []
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to sort users (user_name) by personality (for example : "Openness") by "percentile"

What I came up with so far, based on [elasticsearch: Nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/nested.html) and [elasticsearch: Sorting within nested objects.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting), is this code :

```
    "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "piInfo.profile.personality",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must":
                { "match": { "piInfo.profile.personality.name": "Openness" }} 
            }
          }
      }
    },
    "sort" : {
        "piInfo.profile.personality.percentile" : {
            "order" : "asc",
            "nested": {
                "path": "piInfo.profile.personality",
                "filter": {
                "match": { "piInfo.profile.personality.name": "Openness" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I got this error:

> [nested] nested object under path [piInfo.profile.personality] is not of nested type

And that is logic because I didn't mapp it. I am taking data from an API and I am storing it as it is.

Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you can only use nested queries on nested types.  In other words, you need to declare "personality" as the data type `nested` in your index mapping beore you load any data into it.  The default type is `object`.  Making objects `nested` means **Elasticsearch** will store them in a such a way that the relationship between the fields in each individual object is not lost.  If you don't do that then each field is built into an index independently.

More info here:
[Elasticsearch Nested Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)